# How to stop an IPython cluster without the ipcluster command

Tags: ipython-parallel

I don't start my IPython cluster with the `ipcluster` command but with the individual commands `ipcontroller` and `ipengine` because I use several machines over a network. When starting the cluster with the `ipcluster` command, stopping the cluster is rather straightforward:

`ipcluster stop`

However, I haven't been able to found the procedure when using the individual commands separately.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is by connecting a Client and issuing a shutdown command:

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
c = ipp.Client()
c.shutdown(hub=True)
```

`Client.shutdown()` shuts down engines; adding `hub=True` tells it to bring down the central controller process as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. Is there a way to do this without using a python interpreter?

Comment: @PierreE You could call this in one line from a python script (`python -c 'import ipyparallel as ipp; c=ipp.Client(); c.shutdown(hub=True)`')... Not sure of your question - what can you not do that is constraining you? You could put the above in a shell script and execute that. Otherwise you can put the above in a jupyter cell. You could also kill the various processes in the worst case. What did you try for the `ipcontroller`/`ipengine` route?